# Expo: Custom buttons on VideoPlayer in React Native

Tags: android, ios, video, react-native, expo

I want to render a fullscreen video playback with custom buttons overlayed on top of the video playback (for example a tick mark/cross/circle which I want to render using the TouchableOpacity). I can’t seem to add any sub-components to the Video component. Here is what I am trying to do:-

```
renderVideoPreview() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }}
      >
        <Video
          source={{ uri: this.state.tempRecording }}
          rate={1.0}
          volume={1.0}
          muted={true}
          resizeMode="cover"
          shouldPlay
          isLooping
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <View style={{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
          }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circle}>

            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Video>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I have tried to put the components outside of the Video component but that didn’t achieve what I wanted it to.

```
renderVideoPreview() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }}
      >
        <Video
          source={{ uri: this.state.tempRecording }}
          rate={1.0}
          volume={1.0}
          muted={true}
          resizeMode="cover"
          shouldPlay
          isLooping
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
        <View style={{
          backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circle}>

          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The code resulted in the below output. it whitened out the whole View component even though I specified the backgroundColor: ‘transparent’

[image]

The error I always get is this:- **'Video cannot have any subviews'**

Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Video component can't have children components, as you've discovered, but you can overlay sibling components on top of the video by positioning them absolutely. Conceptually, the gist of this is:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Video />
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
        <Text>Button</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Check out the Expo VideoPlayer component for an example with custom video controls: https://github.com/expo/videoplayer. It lets you render video players like this:

[image: Expo video player with controls]